LexOffice Download File via Lambda
I'm trying to download a file in PDF from LexOffice API via Lambda Function (NodeJS, and Amplify) and return the result to the user who called the Lambda.
I am using NextJS with Typescript.
Problem: From my Website the downloaded PDF is only a blank/white PDF.
So far my Lambda snippet:
            const resInvoice = await axios.get(`https://api.lexoffice.io/v1/files/${invoiceFileId}`, {
                "headers": {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${lexOfficeApiKey}`,
                    'Accept': 'application/pdf',
                },
            });
           
            console.log(resInvoice)

            return {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
                    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
                },
                body: resInvoice.data.toString('base64'),
                isBase64Encoded: true
            };

And here how I handle calling the Lambda and download the PDF.
            const restOperation = post({
                apiName: 'TeachpieRestApi',
                path: '/getinvoicepdf',
                options: {
                    body: {
                        queryParameters: {
                            "invoiceId": invoiceId,
                            "invoideFileId": invoideFileId,
                        },
                    }
                },
            });
            const { body } = await restOperation.response;
            const blobPDF = await body.blob()

            // set the blog type to final pdf
            const file = new Blob([blobPDF], { type: 'application/pdf' });

            // process to auto download it
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF);
            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = fileURL;
            link.download = "Test" + ".pdf";
            link.click();

